# Issue with XML validation

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I'm validating xml file against FIXML's fixml-partiesreference-impl-5-0-SP2.xsd and it is giving an error message " Validation error: The 'http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2:PtyDetlDefReq' element is not declared."
But "PtyDetlDefReq" is already decalred in xsd file. So could anybody explain me how to solve this issue. Many Thanks.

### fixml-partiesreference-impl-5-0-SP2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated:2013-12-08T19:18:30.094-05:00 Revision: FIXML Schema
     Version FIX.5.0SP2 Copyright(c) FIX Protocol Limited. All rights
     reserved. Comments and errors should be posted on the FIX protocol web-site
     http://www.fixprotocol.org -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2"
           xmlns:fm="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2/METADATA"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2/METADATA 
                               fixml-metadata-5-0-SP2.xsd"
           targetNamespace="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
   <xs:include schemaLocation="fixml-partiesreference-base-5-0-SP2.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

---

### fixml-partiesreference-base-5-0-SP2.xsd file's code

```
 <xs:element name="PtyDetlDefReq" 
             type="PartyDetailsDefinitionRequest_message_t"
             substitutionGroup="Message"
             final="#all"/>
```

---

```
 <xs:complexType name="PartyDetailsDefinitionRequest_message_t" 
                 final="#all">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
           PartyDetailsDefinitionRequest can be found in Volume 3 of the
           specification</xs:documentation>
         <xs:appinfo>
           <fm:Xref Protocol="FIX" 
                    name="PartyDetailsDefinitionRequest" 
                    ComponentType="Message"
                    MsgID="134"
                    Section="PreTrade"
                    Category="PartiesReferenceData"/>
         </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="Abstract_message_t">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:group ref="PartyDetailsDefinitionRequestElements"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="PartyDetailsDefinitionRequestAttributes"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
```

---

### My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PtyDetlDefReq ReqID="123" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
               xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2">
  <PtyDetlUpd ListUpdActn="A">
    <PtyDetl ID="55" R="38">
      <Sub ID="C" Typ="26" />
      <Sub ID="M" Typ="220" />
      <Sub ID="Test Test" Typ="235" />
      <Sub ID="RC" Typ="203" />
      <Sub ID="ABCDEF" Typ="204" />
      <Sub ID="1" Typ="222" />
      <Sub ID="1" Typ="223" />
      <Sub ID="ABCDEF" Typ="207" />
      <Sub ID="ABCDEF" Typ="208" />
      <Sub ID="abcd" Typ="209" />
      <Sub ID="ABCDEF" Typ="233" />
      <Sub ID="123456" Typ="210" />
      <Sub ID="ABCDEF" Typ="212" />
    </PtyDetl>
  </PtyDetlUpd>
</PtyDetlDefReq>
```

---

you can download complete xsd files set from http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/pg/extensions/extension-pack?ExtensionID=EP168

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the schema document fragments you have provided, you are right that the element {http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2}PtyDetlDefReq is declared in the schema document described by schema document fixml-partiesreference-impl-5-0-SP2.xsd.

So the most likely cause of the error message you give is that the validator is not actually loading that schema document.

Different XSD validators have different ways of locating schema documents.  How are you telling your validator where to look for a schema document for the target namespace `http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2`?

Just giving the namespace can in principle be enough, if your validator is part of an infrastructure with a local schema repository where it can and will look for schema components by namespace; it can also be enough, if dereferencing the namespace name produces a RDDL document with pointers to suitable schema documents.  But in other cases, you are likely to need to specify a sequence of namespace-name / schema-document-URI pairs when invoking the XSD validator.  (Most XSD validators will take this information from xsi:schemaLocation attributes in the XML instance being validated, but the good ones will also allow the schema to be specified at invocation so that the instance document does not need to be trusted to give correct schema pointers.)

Comment: Hi Sperberg, first I would like to thank you for your response to my issue. We have found that all our xsd files are blocked and we unblocked them in file's Properties and problem was solved.